# "Bob and I" or "Bob and me" when describing a picture

Tags: word-usage, pronouns

Is it "Bob and I"  or "Bob and me" when describing a picture?

I've read the other links but they all use an example with a longer sentence. like "Bob and I went to the store", or "Me and Bob had lunch today."

But what if it's a picture and the sentence below is just "Bob and I"? Is that correct?

Comment: "Bob and I" is not a *sentence*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule here is very simple: the correct word is the one you'd use if there were no "Bob" involved -- so "I went to the store" becomes "Bob and I went to the store," and "She kissed me" becomes "She kissed Bob and me."

So what would you label a picture of just yourself? "This is me" or "This is I"? It's the first one, of course, so the proper caption is "(This is) Bob and me."

Comment: I thank you! .. (or is it Me thanks you!? just kidding)

Comment: While I agree that "this is me" is common and colloquial, there is no reason to say not that it's obvious ("of course"). The predicate nominative "I" is the obvious choice from the standpoint of grammatical consistency.  Knock, knock.  Who's there? It is I.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock grammatical consistency with what?  Most English speakers -- a vast majority, I suppose -- would respond to "who's there" by answering "it's me."

Comment: True. But this would not necessarily be obvious to someone with a knowledge of English grammar but little exposure to colloquial usage.